# How to check if specific index exists in EKL using logstash pipeline?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I want to write a logstash pipeline to check if specific index exists or not in ES env; if yes then mark incoming event as "valid", else "invalid".

To check index validity using cURL :

```
curl -u elastic:elastic -I http://localhost:9200/sampletest1
```

valid output - `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`
invalid output - `HTTP/1.1 400 Not Found`

My logstash script:

```
input {
    beats {
        port => "5044"
    }
}
filter {
    #execute curl to check for index http://localhost:9200/%{process-code}
    #if response has 200 then mutate with add_tags "valid". else add tag "invalid"
    if "valid" in [tags] {
        
    } else {
        #delete event; prevent it from going to output section
    }
}
output {
    #print only valid events
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

I am stuck at 2 # lines mentioned in filter section. We cant use `exec` plugin in filter section !

Comment: You can use an http filter to make a call to elasticsearch.

Comment: Hi @Badger, can you please explain how to use http filter plugin's response? i can call "http://localhost:9200/%{process-code}" using http plugin but dont know how to check whats received, and then process further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it using "[http filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-http.html)" as suggested by Badger in comments.

```
filter {
    json {  source => "message"}
    http {
            url => "http://localhost:9200/%{process-code}"
            verb => "HEAD"
            body_format => "json"
            user => "elastic"
            password => "elastic"
    }
    if "_httprequestfailure" in [tags] {
            #index not present. drop will prevent it from going to output section
            drop {}
    } else {
            #index present
            mutate {    add_tag => [ "found" ]}
    }
}
```

Note: http plugin above adds `_jsonparsefailure` tag in output event; to avoid it we can use `tag_on_json_failure=>[]`.

Ref: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/http-filter-plugin-adds-jsonparsefailure-in-tag/277744